# Swaption Volatility Cube arbitrage

Tags: volatility, arbitrage, swaption

How can I exploit an arbitrage by violating the following no-arbitrage condition (taken from the paper "Arbitrage-Free Construction of the Swaption Cube" by Simon Johnson and Bereshad Nonas):

Swptn(K,T1,T2)+Swptn(K,T2,T3) >= Swptn(K,T1,T3)
with Swptn(A,B,C) being the price of a swaption of strike A, time to option maturity B, time to underlying swap maturity C.

Thanks for any hints.
L.

Answer (score 1):

Exploiting an arbitrage is straightforward. Constructing and noticing one is the hard part. In your case if you know that Swptn(K,T1,T2)+Swptn(K,T2,T3) >= Swptn(K,T1,T3),

Simply sell Swptn(K,T1,T2)+Swptn(K,T2,T3) and buy Swptn(K,T1,T3). Sell the most expensive and buy the cheapest.

L.

Comment: Dear L.,thank you very much for your complete answer. Now I can truly become rich with your smart strategy!